# Python requests - Send two requests on the same page?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to change the username of an account on a website. There are 3 POST parameters required:

1) newName
2) password
3) authenticityToken

**The authenticityToken is randomly generated each time the page is loaded.** It is input type hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticityToken" value="0640ce533fc7a51b88f79ce17cdbd611f4dc2360"/>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the value of the authenticityToken and on the same page POST the 3 parameters required as stated above. At the moment, my code receives an authenticityToken using a GET request, and then sends another POST request. It returns

> Bad authenticity token

The code I am currently using is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://account.mojang.com"

#Login and save cookies
r = requests.post("https://account.mojang.com/login", data={'username':'theUsername','password':'thePassword','remember':'true'})
Logincookies = r.cookies

#Parse the page to get rename link
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
renamePage = None
sources = soup.findAll('a',{"href":True})
for source in sources:
    if("/me/renameProfile/" in source["href"]):
       renamePage = source["href"]


#Get AuthToken

authToken = None
r = requests.get(url + renamePage,cookies=Logincookies)
parser = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
srcs = parser.findAll('input')
for src in srcs:
    if(src["name"] == "authenticityToken"):
        authToken = src["value"]
print(authToken)


r = requests.post(url + renamePage, cookies=Logincookies, data={'newName':'theNewUsername','password':'thePassword','authenticityToken':authToken})
print(r.text)
```

Once again, how can I do this so that the GET and POST request go to together so that it does not use a new page and receive a new authenticityToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to use a library called RoboBrowser and feed it the same session used as my earlier requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

session=requests.session()
r = session.post(...)
r = session.get("...")

browser.open(url+renamePage)
rename_form = browser.get_form(class_='standard')
rename_form['newName'].value = "theNewUser"
rename_form['password'].value = "theNewPass"

browser.submit_form(rename_form)
```

Comment: You do not _need_ RoboBrowser - RoboBrowser is in fact [using request.Session()](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/blob/master/robobrowser/browser.py#L72) itself as @Andersson indicated is a viable way to get what you want - you even create a Session instance via requests.session() (but do not clearly indicate using it) in your answer.

Comment: Nope. I just commented out RoboBrowser code and sent a POST request: r = session.post(url+renamePage,data={'newName':newname,'password':password}) and I received back authenticityToken.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). It should allow you to use same `cookies`, access tokens etc in different requests:

```
s = requests.Session()
url = "https://account.mojang.com"
r = s.post("https://account.mojang.com/login", data={'username':'theUsername','password':'thePassword','remember':'true'})
Logincookies = r.cookies
...
r = s.get(url + renamePage,cookies=Logincookies)
```

P.S. In some cases you might also need to specify client in `headers`, e.g. `headers={ "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0" }`

Comment: I already tried that before I posted it. I think I found a library to fix it though. It's called Robobrowser.